# IndexError at /add_post/ list index out of range

Tags: python, django

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, I recently put if and else method on my media file to catch some error and now I get a brand new one. 
Here's my code.

**media.py**

```
    import json
    from goose import Goose

    def extract(url):
        g = Goose()
        article = g.extract(url=url)
        if article.top_image is None:
            return "hello"
        else:
            resposne = {'image':article.top_image.src}
            return article.top_image.src
```

**views.py**

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
     model = Post
     form_class = PostForm
     template_name = 'main/add_post.html'

     def form_valid(self, form):
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            # any manual settings go here
            self.object.moderator = self.request.user
            self.object.image = extract(self.object.url) 

            self.object.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post', args=[self.object.slug]))

     @method_decorator(login_required)
     def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

            return super(PostCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Post the error please? It is hard to tell where in this code the error occurred and I am sure there is more code we do not have access to.

Comment: Maybe article.top_image isn't null but article.top_image.src is?

Comment: @IbrahimAhmed, error is IndexError at /add_post/ list index out of range
do you need a traceback? It's occuring from env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py in __get__, line 202

Comment: @RyanCori, I'm sorry I'm not sure I get what you're saying. if article.top_image is null it should print hello. and if it's not it posts image(this part works fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your `top_image`'s might not have a `src` attribute defined. You could check like this:

```
def extract(url):
    g = Goose()
    article = g.extract(url=url)
    if article.top_image is None:
        return "hello"
    else:
        if article.top_image.src is None:
            return "hello"
        else:
            resposne = {'image':article.top_image.src}
            return article.top_image.src
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, I solved it similar to your solution :) but I'm having other problem right now. Would you mind looking at the post I made here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624069/why-isnt-my-image-got-saved?noredirect=1#comment56994161_34624069